# npm fails when installing gulp-typescript on Azure

Tags: azure, gulp-typescript

I'm trying to deploy my Azure AppService. The application is written using TypeScript (both server and client). When deploying everything works ok until it's installing gulp-typescript. This is used to transpile TypeScript code as part of postinstall script.

**Package.json:**

```
    {
      "name": "test-webapp",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Test Application",
      "engines": {
        "node": "4.4.6"
      },
      "main": "server.js",
        "scripts": {
          "start": "node server/server.js",
          "typings": "typings",
          "postinstall": "node node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && npm run typings install && node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js ts-compile"
      },
      "author": {
        "name": "liskaj",
        "email": ""
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
        "bower": "^1.7.9",
        "cors": "^2.7.1",
        "express": "^4.14.0",
        "express-session": "^1.14.0",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
        "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
        "request": "^2.73.0",
        "typescript": "^1.8.10",
        "typings": "^1.3.2",
        "winston": "^2.2.0"
      }
    }
```

**Azure log output:**

```
remote: npm ERR! node v4.4.6
remote: npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
remote: npm ERR! path D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\gulp-typescript\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\globstream\node_modules\micromatch\node_modules\braces\node_modules\expand-range\node_modules\fill-range\node_modules\isobject\node_modules\isarray\package.json.3240780430
remote: npm ERR! code EINVAL
remote: npm ERR! errno -4071
remote: npm ERR! syscall rename
remote:
remote: npm ERR! EINVAL: invalid argument, rename 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\gulp-typescript\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\micromatch\node_modules\braces\node_modules\expand-range\node_modules\fill-range\node_modules\isobject\node_modules\isarray\package.json.3240780430' -> 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\gulp-typescript\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\micromatch\node_modules\braces\node_modules\expand-range\node_modules\fill-range\node_modules\isobject\node_modules\isarray\package.json
```

This works fine locally (Windows 7 + Windows 10) and also on Heroku.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution to this?

Comment: Actually yes. This seems to be related to Windows and some gulp modules (long path). So instead of using gulp to transpile .ts files I'm calling tsc directly from npm script:
`node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -p ./client`

Comment: Thanks ! I actually came to a solution on my own - turns out you can use Package.json to point Azure to use a newer version of NPM (3x), which dedupes the dependencies to avoid crazy deep file nesting. `... "engines": {
    "node": "4.6.x",
    "npm": "3.9.x"
  }, ...`  See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/04/20/nodejs-and-npm-versions-on-azure-app-services/) for details.